# How to fill a div with different colors

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-4, html-table

[image]

I need to add different colors for a single table cell as the image given.How can I do that without separating the cell as different div.

Answer (score 4):

You can use css linear gradients like this (this is an example with thwo colors, red and blue):

```
#test{
 background: linear-gradient(red 100px, blue 100px);
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(red 100px, blue 100px);
 background: -o-linear-gradient(red 100px, blue 100px);
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(red 100px, blue 100px);
}
```

Here's the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/eMmE9/

Answer (score 3):

Using CSS3 `linear gradient` you can add multiple background color. Here is a Quick **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/qirehejo/1/edit)**.

All latest browser support it. to work on older browser please add vendor prefix as well. 
Here is the CSS I've used.

```
div{
width:200px;
height:150px;
background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #808000 0%, #808000 20%, #400080 20%, #400080 40%, #FF0080 40%, #FF0080 60%, #FFFF00 60%, #FFFF00 80%, #800040 80%, #800040 100%); /*standard as per W3C*/
}
```

See the outcome here.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This might help you

```
<td bgcolor="#FF0000"></td>
<td bgcolor="#00FF00"></td>
<td bgcolor="#0000FF"></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
 <table id="test">
   <tr>
    <td>
    <div class="block1">
        </div>
          <div class="block1 blue">
        </div>
          <div class="block1 green">
        </div>
          <div class="block1 yellow">
        </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
 </table>
```

**CSS**

```
#test{
height:200px;
width:200px;
     }
.block1
 {
width:200px;
height:50px;
background:red;
 }
 .blue
{
   background:blue;       
 }
.green
{
 background:green;     
}
.yellow
{
background:yellow;     
 }
```

This is the solution . You can check my fiddle too

http://jsfiddle.net/eMmE9/4/

Answer (score 0):

css linear gradients is great option to fullfill your need. you can generate css by selecting your colors and patterns from this **[Site](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/)** with all browser support.